# IndexErrorL list index out of range, when removing items from list

Tags: python, list, loops, copy

I'm trying to make code that removes duplicates from a sorted list. Here is the code I have made:

```
def rduplicate(L):
    Lc = L.copy()
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if L[i]==L[i+1]:
            Lc.remove(L[i])
    return Lc

L=[1,2,3,3,5,6]
print(rduplicate(L))
```

I can't see why the error, "IndexError: list index out of range" is produced.

Comment: it has to do with your last iteration of the loop and the line `L[i]==L[i+1]` - in the last iteration , the value of i would be the last item or max length of the list, in which case i+1 cannot exist as the list has only i elements

Comment: Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: @MandeepSingh stop at `len(L)-1` instead maybe? It depends on what the code is for and how you need it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
if L[i] == len(L):
        break
```

Before your if statement like this code which works:

```
def rduplicate(L):
    Lc = L.copy()
    for i in range(len(L)):
      if L[i] == len(L):
        break
        if L[i]==L[i+1]:
            Lc.remove(L[i])  
    return Lc

L=[1,2,3,3,5,6]
print(rduplicate(L))
```

The error comes after running the loop 6 times and looking for the next (7th) element that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comment, `L[i+1]` tries to access an element that's not in the list in the last iteration of the loop.

You can fix this by skipping that last iteration. This works:

```
def rduplicate(L):
    Lc = L.copy()
    for i in range(len(L)-1):
        if L[i]==L[i+1]:
            Lc.remove(L[i])
    return Lc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def rduplicate(L):
    # reversed iteration
    for i in reversed(range(len(L))):
        # if a value is counted more than 1 remove it
        if L.count(L[i]) > 1:
            L.remove(i)
    return L

L=[1,2,3,3,5,6]
print(rduplicate(L))
```